# Add a hyperlink to a group block?

Tags: block-editor

I have a group of blocks that each contain hyperlinks to the same destination. Google Search Console reports a mobile usability problem "clickable elements too close together." To fix, I want to apply a single hyperlink to an entire Gutenberg group.

Is this possible either with the included Gutenberg blocks or with one from a block library?

Comment: note that this site is a programming stack, for support using the block editor as a user you should ask on the .org support forums

Answer (score 1):

Add a [custom HTML block](https://gogutenberg.com/blocks/custom-html/) immediately before and after the elements you'd like to hyperlink as a unit, using the respective opening and closing tags. No need for a group block.

[image: Custom HTML Block]

Answer (score 1):

Use the anchor functionality. Select the block you want to link to, open the advanced panel, and give it an anchor name, e.g. `banana`. Then link to `#banana`.

[image]

Further reading:

- https://wordpress.org/support/article/page-jumps/

Answer (score -1):

Here is a plugin that does the job very easily:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-options/

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, it's just a recommendation/link. Answers must be self contained. A link can support your answer e.g. further reading, but it cannot _be_ the answer, your answer needs to answer the question without linking offsite

Answer (score -1):

Using JavaScript I see being the only practical way for the time being.
If we create a CSS class called outer-block-link and add it to a link, on page load, it could scan the page and for each link or item with the 'outer-block-link', it would transverse up the document tag tree to the block container and add data-target="{child link URL}".
A second Javascript function would trigger once these parameters have been put in place and add an addEventListener that on clicking would get the data-target value (if available) and redirect the page.